# When do you use the invocation operator with new?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jslint

I noticed that the examples in backbonejs.org do not use the invocation operator.

For example:

```
window.sidebar = new Sidebar;
```

However, jslint complains about this.

Is this another example of jslint being restrictive, or is there a good reason for this warning:

```
Missing ();
```

Comment: I mean, you don't need the `()` if you aren't passing any arguments to the constructor. I think it's just jslint's complaining because (I agree) it looks weird without them. I'm not sure of the ES spec explaining this behavior, or of browser support, but I'd assume it's pretty compatible. I guess you could read into it here: http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2

Comment: jslint is all about removing situations where bugs can hide. Confusion creates situations where bugs can hide. Calling a constructor without `()` can cause confusion or at least uncertainty (was this intentional? a typo? Why was it done this way?). Javascript allows for lots of strange code that will "work." For instance you could try to program in javascript with no `;` at all.

Comment: Noes you dinn't, Nick. You obliquely referenced [hipster Bootstrap coding vs. Crockford](http://blog.esterling.co.uk/2012/04/16/javascript-vs-ruby-hipsters/), didn't you? ;^)

Answer (score 2):

It is just a matter of coding style. They are optional when calling a constructor function with no arguments.

Including them:

- Makes it clear that you are calling a function
- Makes your code consistent with invocations of constructors with arguments
- Makes it simpler to add arguments later